# Switching between three different operating modes with single switch

Tags: switches, component-selection

Let's assume i have a design with one LED and one piezo buzzer, powered by some power source (e.g. battery). The device should now support three different operating modes:

1. Off: Neither the LED nor the piezo buzzer should be turned on.
2. Only the LED should light up.
3. The LED **and** the buzzer should be turned on.

This should be realized with a single package **vertical** switch. I don't want to have multiple switches because this would result in the need of multiple openings for the housing of the device.

So far i found those piano DIP/DIL switches to be very promising, but they are way to complicated to use (from a user perspective).

The ideal switch would be a double (stacked) vertical sliding switch, preferable for SMT soldering. Also it should be as small as possible.

The load is max. ~50mA @ 4.2V, probably even less current.

Any suggestions for some suitable switch?

**OR**

Any suggestions using SP3T standard switches **plus** external circuitry?

EDIT:

This one would be great if it was **vertical**: OS203013MT8QN1

Datasheet: http://www.ckswitches.com/media/1428/os.pdf

Comment: Slide switches. I have seen many with their levels of movement. It should be easy to find them

Comment: I spent hours finding suitable ones. The problem with all slide switches i found so far is, that they have common "grounds" which disqualify them for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO2rgW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit Lab has a limited parts list.