# Creating a multiplexer that selects one of three predefined states

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit

Essentially, I have a circuit that has 4 inputs, and each of these inputs has two possible outputs.

Each input looks like this:

[image: Each input looks like this.]

Basically, I am trying to design a circuit that will switch all connect the inputs tp the outputs in 3 different configurations depending on an input signal given, as shown:
[image]

The goal is to have a three position switch that will switch between these modes. What IC or circuit should I use to acheive this?

Edit 1: here are more details. The images below show 5 drivers, but the functional diagram I provided is for a single driver.

Mode 1
[image: mode 1]

Mode 2

[image: Mode 2]

Mode 3

[image: Mode 3]

basically the goal is instead of using jumpers to instead control this change electrically.

Comment: Didn't you or someone else ask this exact question an hour or two ago?

Comment: @Hearth Not that I could find. If you think it is a duplicate please link me to the question you are referencing and I will close my question.

Comment: Oh, no, never mind--it was something with a very similar title that I saw earlier today, but is unrelated. ([if you're curious](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282553/switching-between-three-different-operating-modes-with-single-switch))

Comment: What do you want on an output when it is not selected? Does it matter?

Comment: @KevinWhite If you are referring to mode 2, there should be no connection.

Comment: @3ddavies - Not jsut mode 2 but also mode 1 and 3. WHat is supposed to happen to the unselected outputs. It would be useful if you explained what the signals are and the reason for selecting them like this.

Comment: @KevinWhite Essentially I am creating a circuit to switch between the different operating modes of a TMC2209 stepper motor driver. The pins not connected in the diagram should not be connected to anything.

Comment: basically an 8P1T  switch with 3:8 controlled logic states  with 4 analog inputs and 4 analog outputs with some undefined floating states

Comment: @3ddavies - But what are the signals? Analog, digital, voltage levels and current levels. You need to give more information. Where is the stepper motor driver? At the input or the output? If they are digital signals they usually do not want to be connected to nothing. They should be set high or low. Draw a diagram of the source and the destination of the signals.

Comment: @KevinWhite I updated the question.

Comment: such a fancy 83 page IC spec, yet  no acceleration control or buffered seek control

Answer (score 0):

The CD4053 has three independently controllable SPDT analog switches, with a global inhibit.  One chip can handle all three modes for inputs 1, 2, and 4.  Input 3 never is inhibited, so that would use one channel of a second CD4053, with the inhibit input grounded.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4053b.pdf?ts=1634601279843&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4053B